# Grouping fingers to move with hand

Tags: rigging, 3d-printing, makehuman

[Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/d6a5dc4fce264133930160d9965e02b4)
I import my MakeHuman figure into Blender 3.0.0 apply IK to middle finger to move the arm.
I then close fingers together to give me a better chance of 3d printing.
When I move the hand using the IK linked finger the other fingers move all over the place.
I know I am doing something wrong but cannot work it out.
Any help pse?
Eddy[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hello please share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/